# Unable to get location with HTML5 Geolocation and Android with different user

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, geolocation

I'm developing an app for Android which will be runned on a single type of device, which is - Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 8.0 - running on Android KitKat 4.4.2.

We have multiple users on our devices, the Owner and a Restricted Profile account, which is used by workers in our company.

My app has a `WebView` in which it loads our Web Application from a Web server which is responsive in it's layout and on login request we require the visitor to Share his/hers Location with HTML5 Geolocation.

Sharing one's location works like a charm on Web (using either a Browser on a computer or on a mobile devices), works fine on the App when the Owner account initiates it, etc.

However, if I run this application as the Restricted Profile account, I only reach the timeout I've set in my JavaScript, message appears and nothing else happends.

This is my JavaScript for invoking the Share Location thing:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPositionForMobileApp, getLocationErrorHandler, {frequency: 5000, maximumAge: 0, timeout: 60000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
} else {
    $('.panel-body').first().html('<small>Your browser doesn\'t support <strong>HTML5 Geolocation</strong>.<br /> Please install a newer version of your Internet Browser.</small>');
}
```

JavaScript callbacks for HTML5 Geolocation API are:

```
function getPositionForMobileApp(position) {
    $('input#position').val(position.coords.latitude + ';' + position.coords.longitude);

    $.post('/user/login?usingMobileApp=true', {position: (position.coords.latitude + ';' + position.coords.longitude)}, function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            $('.panel-body').first().html(data.html);

            // this is for testing/debugging purposes
            $('.col-md-12.text-center small').html(position.coords.latitude + ' ----------- ' + position.coords.longitude);

            $('input#login').focus();
        } else {
            $('.panel-body').first().html('<small><strong>Request is not valid!</strong><br /><br />We've blocked your IP Address: <kbd>' + data.ip + '</kbd> for next 24 hours.</small>');
        }
    }, 'json');
}
}
```

As mentioned before, this works well on other Browser on computers and Browsers on mobile devices, except when I run my URL from a Chrome Browser on a mobile device, using the Restricted Profile account - it doesn't even prompt me on Chrome whether to Share location or block it.

When I run it this way using the Built in Internet Browser app, it prompts me, if I accept, I get my position regulary.

So I belive this has to do something with user restrictions built by Samsung/Android, I don't know who any more.

These are my permissions in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

I'm using all those for different purposes; I don't know if some maybe colliding with others or something, but I need all of those.

This is my `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` method override:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // I doubt that this is needed at all, but I've added it anyway
        GeolocationPermissions.getInstance().allow(origin);

        // as said, works well on other places...
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);

        // after so much frustration, I've added the parent method.
        super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, callback);
    }
});
```

I don't know anything anymore; can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this, but didn't had the time to answer it before.

So, the thing is with the restricted profiles in Android, which restrict using HTML5 Geolocation API, Browser Notifications and many other new features present in modern-day browsers.

Solution was to avoid using restricted profiles for these kind of apps which implement HTML5 Geolocation API within the app, mainly with WebView's.

We gave our users full access to the system/device and it works flawlessly.

I hope this will help anyone in the future.

---

By the way, I am not sure if this issue is resolved in newer Android versions like `5.x` and `6`, but I surely hope it is.